# Могли бы вы мне помочь с библиотекой openpyxl

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

можете подсказать что не правильно я сделал в коде .должно получиться как в картинке[image: вот конечный результат]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import openpyxl
root = Tk()
root.title("Учет больных корью  в школе")


def load_data():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('lolo.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active
    list_values = list(sheet.values)
    print(list_values)

    for col_name in list_values[0]:
        treeview.heading(col_name, text=col_name)

    for value_tuple in list_values[1:]:
        treeview.insert('', tkinter.END, values=value_tuple)
```

Comment: Это весь код, минимально достаточный для воспроизведения? Какая-то ошибка, где она в вопросе? В чем конкретно вопрос, что именно не получается?